# How do I prevent my program from printing an extra slash?

Tags: c++

```
while (stack.is_not_empty()) {
  cout << "/" << stack.pop();
}
```

Ideally, my output should be: /feb/12/1983

but I'm getting: //feb/12/1983

I don't understand how this could possible print two slashes in the beginning. There is no other code that prints out anything else out.

Comment: First element of the stack is empty string?

Comment: Or first element of the stack starts with a slash :)

Comment: Sweet fancy Moses, I'm an idiot. Of course, the empty string. Thanks guys.

Comment: @user2671760 - Learn to use a debugger

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized.


Comment: @H2CO3 please explain-- he had a problem, said what he tried, explained why it was wrong, and asked for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked the values that are in the stack? If you print them out one per line you might find an unexpected value such as an empty string.